# How do I replace the built in '-h' action in python using argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am creating a command line tool in python, and I'm using argparse to parse my input.

I want to use '-h' as an action, but that is already automatically assigned to --help. How can I override this and have an -h action?

Comment: Why? That's likely to be very irritating for your users.

Comment: Your question is almost a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075241/move-help-to-a-different-argument-group-in-python-argparse

Comment: @jonrsharpe I needed it the other day, because I was building a wrapper around some other specialised software. I wanted to keep the flags identical between the wrapper and the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
```

Thanks for asking, because I had the same problem the other day and only bothered checking the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help) now.