# Reorder Python argparse argument groups

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using `argparse` and I have a custom argument group `required arguments`. Is there any way to change the order of the argument groups in the help message? I think it is more logical to have the required arguments before optional arguments, but haven't found any documentation or questions to help.

For example, changing this:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] -i INPUT [-o OUTPUT]

Foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                      Output file name

required arguments:
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                      Input file name
```

to this:

```
usage: foo.py [-h] -i INPUT [-o OUTPUT]

Foo

required arguments:
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                      Input file name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                      Output file name
```

(example taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180527/argparse-required-arguments-listed-under-optional-arguments))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might consider adding an explicit optional arguments group:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo', add_help=False)

required = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
required.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input file name', required=True)

optional = parser.add_argument_group('optional arguments')
optional.add_argument("-h", "--help", action="help", help="show this help message and exit")
optional.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Output file name', default='stdout')

parser.parse_args(['-h'])
```

You can move the help action to your optional group as 
described here: 
[Move "help" to a different Argument Group in python argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075241/move-help-to-a-different-argument-group-in-python-argparse)

As you can see, the code produces the required output:

```
usage: code.py -i INPUT [-h] [-o OUTPUT]

Foo

required arguments:
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT
                        Input file name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        Output file name
```

Answer (score 7):

The parser starts out with 2 argument groups, the usual `positional` and `optionals`.  The `-h` help is added to `optionals`.  When you do `add_argument_group`, a group is created (and returned to you).  It is also appended to the `parser._action_groups` list.

When you ask for help (`-h`) `parser.format_help()` is called (you can do that as well in testing).  Look for that method in `argparse.py`.  That sets up the help message, and one step is:

```
    # positionals, optionals and user-defined groups
    for action_group in self._action_groups:
        formatter.start_section(action_group.title)
        formatter.add_text(action_group.description)
        formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
        formatter.end_section()
```

So if we reorder the items in the `parser._action_groups` list, we will reorder the groups in the display.  Since this is the only use of `_action_groups` it should be safe and easy.  But some people aren't allowed to peak under the covers (look or change `._` attributes).

The proposed solution(s) is to make your own groups in the order you want to see them, and make sure that the default groups are empty (the `add_help=False` parameter).  That's the only way to do this if you stick with the public API.

Demo:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo')
g1 = parser.add_argument_group('REQUIRED')
g1.add_argument('--bar', required=True)
g1.add_argument('baz', nargs=2)

print(parser._action_groups)   
print([group.title for group in parser._action_groups])
print(parser.format_help())

parser._action_groups.reverse()  # easy inplace change
parser.print_help()
```

Run result:

```
1504:~/mypy$ python stack39047075.py
```

`_actions_group` list and titles:

```
[<argparse._ArgumentGroup object at 0xb7247fac>,
 <argparse._ArgumentGroup object at 0xb7247f6c>,
 <argparse._ArgumentGroup object at 0xb721de0c>]
['positional arguments', 'optional arguments', 'REQUIRED']
```

default help:

```
usage: stack39047075.py [-h] --bar BAR foo baz baz

positional arguments:
  foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

REQUIRED:
  --bar BAR
  baz
```

after reverse:

```
usage: stack39047075.py [-h] --bar BAR foo baz baz

REQUIRED:
  --bar BAR
  baz

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

positional arguments:
  foo
1504:~/mypy$
```

Another way to implement this is to define a `ArgumentParser` subclass with a new `format_help` method.  In that method reorder the list used in that `for action_group...` loop.

Answer (score 7):

This is admittedly a hack, and is reliant on the changeable internal implementation, but after adding the arguments, you can simply do:

```
parser._action_groups.reverse()
```

This will effectively make the required arguments group display above the optional arguments group. Note that **this answer is only meant to be descriptive, not prescriptive**.

---

Credit: [answer by hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39048205/832230)