# Action Groups in Argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I was going through some `argparse` code when I saw this. I have used `argparse` to create command line tools in the past but never came across this. I cannot find its documentation either.

What are `action groups` and why do we use them?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser._action_groups.pop()
```

Comment: They seem to be the implementation of [argument groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups)

Comment: Anything prefixed with `_` in `argparse` is not meant as public API, even if it may be accessed.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327091/python-argparse-grouping-parent-parser-arguments-into-groups) for what this might do.

Comment: Note the `_` prefix; it's an undocumented implementation detail that you shouldn't use directly.

Comment: `format_help` passes these groups to the `HelpFormater` for display purposes.  The list starts with 2 groups, `postional` and `optionals`, and `add_action_group` can create more.  Every `Action` (created by `add_argument`) belongs to a group.  They are not used for parsing, just help.